# Error parsing JSONobject

Tags: php, android, json

I have a login app for android that uses JSON to parse data from the database to the app. The php api that accepts the http request is recognized by a tag, that is either "login" or "register" like so:

```
if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') {
    "Do stuf
    } else {
       echo "access denied";
```

The app has been working fine, but now im only getting the response "Access denied".

```
public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", "login"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
    // return json
    // Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
    return json;
}
```

This is the JSONobject that sends the request, and Im suspecting that its not sending the tag properly. Does anyone have a clue of whats going on?

Update: Added JSONparser.class

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSON", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

}

Comment: Why don't you just debug yourself into some more info by just seeing in your PHP script what actually comes in at the $_POST array

Comment: I echoed the $_POST["tag"] and it returned Null, so for some reason the JSONparser is not sending the data.

Comment: 2 things you can replace all of (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') with strlen($_POST['tag'])>0  next up doesn't the jsonParser.getJSONFromURL use $_GET not $_POST

Comment: Doesn't help you have an error in your php either you have "Do stuf it should be //do stuff.  As you can see from the code highlighting above its a syntax error if its like that in your live file then that won't be helping.

Comment: Sorry Dave, that was just an example. //Do stuff was just referring to storing/getting stuff from a database. So you think the problem can be that the script is receiving a $_GET array instead of a $_POST array?

Comment: Could be but also noticed you have `sb.append(line + "n");` it should be `sb.append(line + "\n");` for the new line addition to split the output.  Thats not the main issue but could cause you a display issue on your output all the same (problem is we're just not receiving the correct output :) )  Try knocking up a dummy html page that does a simple form post to your php page. make sure the php page is receiving the correct information and returning the expected results first.  Then it narrows it down to a fault with your java not your php.

Comment: My java's a little rusty does `httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));` not just pull all your list params into a string rather than a correctly formatted post array? do you not need to foreach on your list and add each post entity separately as key => value pairs.

Comment: also not seeing a `JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();` it should be just above `JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);` in your login call

Answer (score 0):

Actually looking at it it looks like you're using the JSON query wrong anyway unles there's more code you're not showing us. You're missing the creation of the jsonParser class

> `public class JSONParser {`
>
> ```
> static InputStream is = null;
> static JSONObject jObj = null;
> static String json = "";
>
> // constructor
> public JSONParser() {
>
> }
>
> public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
>
>     // Making HTTP request
>     try {
>         // defaultHttpClient
>         DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
>         HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
>
>         HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
>         HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
>         is = httpEntity.getContent();          
>
>     } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     } catch (IOException e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
>
>     try {
>         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
>                 is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
>         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
>         String line = null;
>         while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
>             sb.append(line + "\n");
>         }
>         is.close();
>         json = sb.toString();
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
>     }
>
>     // try parse the string to a JSON object
>     try {
>         jObj = new JSONObject(json);
>     } catch (JSONException e) {
>         Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
>     }
>
>     // return JSON String
>     return jObj;
>
> } }
> ```

See this site for more information http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: Actually that is were i got this code. It has been working perfectly, but i didn't touch my project for a few weeks and now it sends the $_POST array values as null. Should i put up the JSONParser.class so you can view it?

Comment: It would certainly help to see your full code yeah.  However if its been working perfectly and suddenly stopped chances and you haven't changed either the inbound requested file or your processing file the chances are the issue is with a server config somewhere rather than with your code.  Its either causing a different reponse from the end server or your local server isn't processing the requests correctly

Comment: I added the JSONParser.class. I tried to echo out the $_POST but it was null. Is it possible that it sends the data as $_GET?

Comment: When you're calling your json parser class you are correctly initing the class aren't you `new JSONParser` and passing it the correct input variables for the stuff you want to post to the remote page?